# Improving Redis Lua script performance

Tags: node.js, performance, redis, lua, ioredis

I'm trying to save entities into redis. Each entity is a JSON (I don't do any operation on that json so I don't think (?) redis-json will help me here).

My service receives (over kafka-topic) alot of entities. some of them are updates of other entities.

Each entity has a "eventId" (it's like "category"),"bms" (it's like "entity-id"). Multiple entities with the same `eventId` may have different `bms`.

To be able to support consumer-groups (multiple kafka consumers) which all of them will save the entities in Redis: Each entity has a version (integer >=0).

#### Logic

Save the entity only if the `new` (from kafka) entity's version > `current` (inside redis) entity's version.

#### Data

My service consume upto 1k entities from the kafka per second. it means I need to `SET` 1k times at most per second.

#### Solutions

- I read in batch from the kafka-topic, so I have the ability to call redis with `multi` or `pipeline`.
- I assumed there is no way to avoid lua for atomicity when comparing "new" version with "current" version.

##### 1. Lua Invokation Per Entity

```lua
local event_id = KEYS[1]
local bms = ARGV[1]
local new_version = tonumber(ARGV[2])
local new_offer = ARGV[3]

local bms_offer_hm_key = 'bms-offers--' .. event_id
local bms_version_hm_key = 'bms-version--' .. event_id

local current_version = tonumber(redis.call('HMGET',bms_version_hm_key, bms))

if current_version == nil or current_version < new_version then
  redis.call('HMSET',bms_version_hm_key, bms, new_version)
  redis.call('HMSET',bms_offer_hm_key, bms, new_offer)
  return 1
else
  return 0
end
```

##### Performance:

- redis 1k insers  -> 0.050s
- redis 2k insers  -> 0.100s
- redis 10k insers -> 0.400s

##### 2. Lua Invokation for all Entities

```lua
local j=1
for i=1, #KEYS do
  local event_id = KEYS[i]
  local bms = ARGV[j]
  local new_version = tonumber(ARGV[j+1])
  local new_offer = ARGV[j+2]

  local bms_offer_hm_key = 'bms-offers--' .. event_id
  local bms_version_hm_key = 'bms-version--' .. event_id
  
  local current_version = tonumber(redis.call('HMGET',bms_version_hm_key, bms))
  
  if current_version == nil or current_version < new_version then
    redis.call('HMSET',bms_version_hm_key, bms, new_version)
    redis.call('HMSET',bms_offer_hm_key, bms, new_offer)
  end
  j=j+3
end
```

##### Performance:

- redis 1k insers  -> 0.200s

#### 3. Lua Invokation Per Entity - Single HM

- Now I'm using `HSET` instead of `HMSET`. Thanks to @raina77ow.

```lua
local molly_event_id = KEYS[1]
local bms = ARGV[1]
local new_version = tonumber(ARGV[2])
local new_offer = ARGV[3]

local key = 'molly-offers::' .. molly_event_id
local bms_sub_key = "bms::" .. bms
local version_sub_key = "version::" .. bms

local current_version = tonumber(redis.call('HMGET',key, version_sub_key))

if current_version == nil or current_version < new_version then
  redis.call('HSET',key, version_sub_key, new_offer, bms_sub_key, new_version)
  return 1
else
  return 0
end
```

##### Performance

- redis 1k insers  -> 0.040s
- redis 2k insers  -> 0.080s
- redis 10k insers -> 0.400s

---

#### More Performance & Info

My above metrics are based on docker-redis ontop of macbook pro:

```
macos catalina 10.15.1 (19B2093)
2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7
16 GB 2667 MHz DDR4
```

When trying to run 1k random sets (with the same entities) (without lua script):

- 1k insers  -> 0.025s
- 2k insers  -> 0.050s
- 10k insers -> 0.211s
- 45k insers -> 1.000s

I'm not in production yet, but when I will, redis will run ontop of k8s pod.

- single redis instace
- AOF + after every write
- I'm still investigating [Redis Labs - Your Cloud Can’t Do That: 0.5M ops + ACID @<1ms Latency!](https://redislabs.com/blog/your-cloud-cant-do-that-0-5m-ops-acid-1msec-latency/)

---

## Questions

1. Is there a way to make the lua script faster? I'm open for any change!
2. I afriad blocking other clients from reading the entities while the lua scripts are blocking redis. multi-node will create additional distributed-logic complexity which I would like to avoid if possible.

Comment: Most likely I'm missing something (not really familiar with Lua), but: 1) isn't HMSET deprecated, and 2) what is `bms` in this case, is it JSON that you want to store? Am I right in understanding that there's as many hashes in your Redis as there are event_ids? (multiplied by 2)

Comment: (1) Thanks! I will try to move to `HSET` and update the question. (2) Yes! (Multiple entities with the same `eventId` may have different `bms`).

Comment: Does it make sense to use a single hash for version numbers, using some kind of composite key?

Comment: In your idea, I will need to save all the versions of every "bms". so the number of key-values in the HM will be `bms`*`versions per bms`. that could work but in my server, I sometimes need to run `hmget` on specific `eventId` and I don't want redis to give me back too much keys.

Comment: But as I saw that `HSET` supports batching, maybe it's a better idea to save the versions and `bms`s in the same HM so I could run only a single `HSET` in the first lua script. I will also test that.

Comment: @raina77ow we have a 20% improvement :) Look at solution 3. Can we do better?

Comment: Well, you should have at least 1 read operation and at least 1 write operation in that script, so I suppose it's pretty close to what's possible with that approach. The biggest limiting factor that I see here is having a single hash per event_id entity; if only it were possible to a single hash overall with keys combining `molly_event_id` with version, you would have been able to query a chunk of those simultaneously, drastically decreasing the number of HMGETs. But that's just an idea; I'm not sure the end result will be much better.